# Custom List View With scroll Gesture option not click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, drop-down-menu

I wanted to make List view which allow user to select option without tap on List Item, item will be selected by swipe gesture similar to stack.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCDM3.png)View

as given in this image list will move like scroll (changes option with swipe) to avoid picking up finger

Please tell me if you find any libary or widget or any other way in android

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

create listview or recyclerview and must create selector for background items()
when clicked item in adapter.

> this is an example selector for edittext when focused

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_focused="true">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/primary" />
    </shape>

</item>

<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/gray" />
    </shape>

</item>
```

Comment: I meant with it more like list WheelScrollView in flutter where rectangle remained same but list can be drag up and down which item is selected will be inside the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

#### In activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    tools:showPaths="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Not Required"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="not Recieved"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Partially Recieved"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Recieved"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

then in

##### activity_main_scene.xml

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/first"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/second"
        motion:duration="10">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/button"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
             />
    </Transition>
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/second"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/third"
        motion:duration="10">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/button"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            />
    </Transition>
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/third"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/fourth"
        motion:duration="10">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/button"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/first">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            >
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="BackgroundColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#ddd" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/second">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="BackgroundColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#ddd" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/third">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view"
            android:layout_marginTop="-100dp">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="BackgroundColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#ddd" />
        </Constraint>
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/fourth">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view"
            android:layout_marginTop="-150dp">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="BackgroundColor"
                motion:customColorValue="#ddd" />
        </Constraint>
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

there is no additional changes is needed in java or in kotline

I found this in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout)